# pl sql decode function for use to check two values

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

In the select statement i need to return a value based on the data on other two colomns. For example,

```
select clarify, clarify_rece_date, clarify_process_date
from test_db;
```

So the clarify should return yes if both clarify_rece_date and clarify_process_date is not null and if they null clarify should return No.

I could have use decode here if i want to check only onle column as below,

```
 select decode(clarify_rece_date, null,'Yes','No') clarify, clarify_rece_date,      clarify_process_date
    from test_db;
```

But how can i check for both columns in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a rather complex `DECODE`.  However, it would make far more sense to use a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN clarify_rece_date IS NOT NULL AND 
                  clarify_process_date IS NOT NULL
             THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
         END) clarify,
       clarify_rece_date,
       clarify_process_date
  FROM test_db
```